# My store is not populating with a simple model data

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, store

I have a basic users.json file, a user model and a users store. The size of the store is 0 when I call getCount().

My initial idea was to add a listener for the load event. However, even just calling getStore() returns empty data.

Can you see were I have gone wrong?

```
    {
    "users":[
        {
            "name": "Mike Henderson",
        },
        {
            "name": "Sally Michael",
        },
        {
            "name": "Rory Muldoon",
        }
    ]
}


Ext.define('TP.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: ['name']
    }
});

Ext.define('TP.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config:{
        autoload: true,
        model: 'TP.model.User',
        storeId: 'Users',
        proxy : {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data/users.json',
            reader: {
                rootProperty: 'users',
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'TP',

    views: ['Main'],

    models:['User'],

    stores:['Users'],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('TP.view.Main'));

        Ext.getStore('Users').on('load', this.onStoreLoad, this);
        console.log(Ext.getStore('Users').getCount());

    },

    onStoreLoad: function(self, records, success, operation) {
        console.log("loaded store");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the end, it was simple typo.

In the store config - autoload needs to be autoLoad (Capital L)